# Necromancer: leech on hit and leech on crit scaling

Tags: guild-wars-2

What do these passive scale from?

Do they scale only from healing stat, or do they also scale with damage?

Comment: Can you please list the names of the passives you're referring to?

Comment: @RavenDreamer Vampiric and Vampiric Precision for example.

Comment: @RavenDreamer Dont be lazy, there are only 1350 passives, you can easily browse them and find the ones he is refering to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking into the two specific abilities you've mentioned, I came across [this page on the Guild Wars 2 wiki](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Life_stealing) dealing specifically with life stealing, which mentions the following two things:

> Siphon Health from Vampiric is capped at 25 base, it gets to 38 with Bloodthirst. It doesn't scale with power or healing power.

This indicates that the Vampiric ability does not scale with healing power, and is capped at a specific value, so does not scale with damage done either.

> Siphon Health from Vampiric Precision heals for 31 (without Healing power)

This indicates that [Vampiric Precision](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Vampiric_Precision) does scale with healing power, but doesn't mention the scale of which healing power affects this ability.

Both of these abilities are affected by the [Bloodthirst](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Bloodthirst) ability.